# groupby() Col A, count Col C, and count unique column B

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, pivot

I have a dataframe with multiple columns.  I want to groupby column A (which is a person's name).  Then I want to count **total** number of rows in column C grouped by column A.  I also want to count number of **unique** rows in Column B grouped by column A.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried? For example, are you familiar with `GroupBy.agg()`? Are you aware of agg funcs `count` and `nunique`? (or `len` instead of `count` if you want to include missing values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'C':'size', 'B':'nunique'})
```

although really, number of rows in `C` should just be the same with number of rows in `B`. This should also work

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['size','nunique'])
```